# Can  I add timeout for ftpslib connection?

Tags: python

Can I add timepout for ftps connection and each command on ftp server ?

```
r  = ftpslib.FTP_TLS()
...
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html I think this only applies to the connection phase. Did not use this library on my own so I can't say if the other operations are blocking.

Answer (score 1):

In python >= 2.6, the [timeout option](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) has been added to `FTP`constructor. It will be used for each blocking operation (ie connection, receive, sending...).
In python >= 2.7, the  `FTP_TLS` object has been added (with timeout).

In python < 2.7, you'll have to modify the default global timeout on socket module with [`socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout) before creating the FTP or FTP_TLS object.

Comment: @eryksun : Thanks, I updated my answer, I didn't notice the _new in version 2.7_